# Automapper custom converter for open generic

Tags: c#, generics, automapper

Mapping [open generics](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Open-Generics) is possible in Automapper, however I have come accros some issue trying to combine it with custom type converters.

The following

```
cfg.CreateMap(typeof(IEnumerable<>), typeof(MyCustomCollectionType<>))
.ConvertUsing(typeof(MyConverter));
```

with MyConverter looking like this:

```
class MyConverter : ITypeConverter<object, object>
{
    public object Convert(object source, object destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        //... do conversion
    }
}
```

does just throw an exception when the mapping is created:

> 'System.InvalidOperationException' in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: This operation is only valid on generic types.

How can I define a custom type converter for open generic types? What interface do I need to implement?

Comment: Update the mapping as below and check,
`cfg.CreateMap<object, object>().ConvertUsing(new MyConverter());`

Comment: Then this converter will kick in for about everything which is not my intention. On initialization it will throw _Expression of type 'System.Object' cannot be used for assignment to type 'System.Double'_.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Converters for open generics need to be generic types. It would look something like:

```
public class MyConverter<TSource, TDest> 
    : ITypeConverter<IEnumerable<TSource>, MyCustomCollectionType<TDest>> {
    public MyCustomCollectionType<TDest> Convert(
        IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
        MyCustomCollectionType<TDest> dest, 
        ResolutionContext context) {
        // you now have the known types of TSource and TDest
        // you're probably creating the dest collection
        dest = dest ?? new MyCustomCollectionType<TDest>();
        // You're probably mapping the contents
        foreach (var sourceItem in source) {
            dest.Add(context.Mapper.Map<TSource, TDest>(sourceItem));
        }
        //then returning that collection
        return dest;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried this and cannot get it to work at all. I always get an exception stating "Unable to cast object of type 'RestDataConverter`2[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[DocumentRecord],System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TDocument]]' to type 'AutoMapper.ITypeConverter`2[RestData`1[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[DocumentRecord]],RestData`1[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Document]]]'. "

Comment: I get the same error, this is not the solution